# Error: Cannot find module 'ipfs' web3.min.js:1:155

Tags: node.js, npm, ipfs

I Can't work with node module ipfs.js 
console shows error: "Cannot find module 'ipfs'"

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

node --version == v8.10.0 
npm --version == 5.6.0 
ipfs version == 0.4.13

My package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ipfs": "^0.28.2",
    "web3": "^0.20.6"
  }
}
```

My app.js:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const node = new IPFS()
// // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
web3 = new Web3(new `Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));`
```

When I run in command line, its works:

```
> const IPFS = require('ipfs')
undefined
> const node = new IPFS()
undefined
> Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4003/ws/ipfs/QmYwqrDJCQEiY2fijnwpPhhsG5w8rVxCTjK7duxtPyt24J
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/ipfs/QmYwqrDJCQEiY2fijnwpPhhsG5w8rVxCTjK7duxtPyt24J
Swarm listening on /ip4/192.168.2.103/tcp/4002/ipfs/QmYwqrDJCQEiY2fijnwpPhhsG5w8rVxCTjK7duxtPyt24J
```

Comment: how are you requiring `Web3` ?

Comment: like this `var Web3 = require('web3');`?

Comment: If it does work in command line, when doesn't it work? The steps for reproducing the " "Cannot find module 'ipfs'" " error is missing from your post

Comment: yes >>> var Web3 = require('web3');

Comment: var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem.
I had no experience with node, so I completely confused its use, in the issue of server-side and client-side use. My intention was to use ipfs in the browser

I am creating a Dapp using the Truffle framework, and the truffle provides a "web3.min.js" file, this library was conflicting with "var ipfs = require ('ipfs').

The solution was simple, I'm using the js-ipfs library only in the browser:

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#use-in-the-browser

Now my code it's:

my html:

```
<script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myjs.js"></script>
```

my app.js:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
console.log(web3);
console.log(Ipfs);
```